# How to define separate configuration for subproject

Tags: autoconf, automake

I have a project with two module (client and server).
Each module is in subfolder of it's own, with it's own make file.
I have single configure.ac file in the project's root directory.

We use AC_SEARCH_LIBS to set compilation flags for the project.
The problem is that both modules need to use different libraries (server needs pthread, client does not).

How is it possible to set different compilation flags for the different modules?

What is the best practice?

Do I need to split configure.ac ? (if yes, how it should be done correctly)

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to split into multiple `configure.ac`.

The trick is, to create different substitution variables for each library, which you can then use independently in your `Makefile.am`s

configure.ac (excerpt):

```
AC_SEARCH_LIBS([fooFun], [foo], [FOO_LIBS="-lfoo"])
AC_SEARCH_LIBS([barFun], [bar], [BAR_LIBS="-lbar"])
AC_SEARCH_LIBS([bazFun], [baz], [BAZ_LIBS="-lbaz"])
AC_SUBST([FOO_LIBS])
AC_SUBST([BAR_LIBS])
AC_SUBST([BAZ_LIBS])
```

and server/Makefile.am (excerpt):

```
server_LDADD = @FOO_LIBS@ @BAR_LIBS@
```

resp. client/Makefile.am (excerpt):

```
client_LDADD = @BAZ_LIBS@
```

Comment: this doesn't work. Trying to build the subproject it says `cannot find @FOO_LIBS@: no such file or directory`