# Modifying configure.ac - check for package presence

Tags: configure, autotools

My main development platform is Gentoo on Linux. However, recently I tried to build my program on the fresh VM install on Debian.

My program contains of main binary and couple of dll/so/dylib libraries. One of the libraries depends on the presence of unixODBC/iODBC.

I was told by unixODBC maintainers to use `odbc_config` script to identify the build parameters.

When I build on Gentoo - everything works fine. There is no problems.

However, when I build on Debian - the build fails because apparently Debian does not produce odbc_config script and instead in this case rely on pkg-config.

So, I need to add a test in configure.ac to check for odbc_config script presence and pass it along to one of the so files generation (lets call it `libodbc_lib` project).

Could someone please help me with this?

EDIT:

Is this correct to be put in configure.ac:

```
AC_CHECK_PROG(ODBC,odbc_config,yes)
if test x"${ODBC}" == x"yes" ; then
    ODBC_CFLAGS = `odbc_config --cflags`
    ODBC_LIBS = `odbc_config --libs` -lodbcinst
else
    ODBC_CFLAGS = `pkg-config odbc --cflags`
    ODBC_LIBS = `pkg-config odbc --libs` -lodbcinst
fi

AC_SUBST(ODBC_CFLAGS)
AC_SUBST(ODBC_LIBS)
```

If it is - how do I use ODBC_FLAGS/ODBC_LIBS in my subproject?

EDIT2:

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46296993/how-to-define-separate-configuration-for-subproject) I used the following code:

In the main configure.ac:

```
AC_CHECK_PROG(ODBC,odbc_config,yes)
if test x"${ODBC}" == x"yes" ; then
    ODBC_CFLAGS = `odbc_config --cflags`
    ODBC_LIBS = `odbc_config --libs` -lodbcinst
else
    ODBC_CFLAGS = `pkg-config odbc --cflags`
    ODBC_LIBS = `pkg-config odbc --libs` -lodbcinst
fi

AC_SUBST(ODBC_CFLAGS)
AC_SUBST(ODBC_LIBS)
```

In the libodbc_lib/Makefile.am:

```
libodbc_lib_la_CXXFLAGS = -I../../dbinterface \
        -DUNICODE \
        -DUNIXODBC \
        -I@ODBC_CFLAGS@

libodbc_lib_la_LDFLAGS = -L../dbinterface \
        -ldbinterface \
        @ODBC_LIB@
```

I regenerated configure, run it successfully and then tried running `make`.

I got following error:

```
CXXLD    libodbc_lib.la
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find @ODBC_LIB@: No such file or directory
```

What I did wrong?

EDIT3:

After fixing the missing `S`, I got following compile commands:

```
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/igor/dbhandler/Debug/libodbc'
/bin/sh ../libtool  --tag=CXX   --mode=compile g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I/home/igor/dbhandler/libodbc -I..    -I../../dbinterface -DUNICODE -DUNIXODBC -I@IODBC_CFLAGS@ -g -O0 -MT libodbc_lib_la-database_odbc.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libodbc_lib_la-database_odbc.Tpo -c -o libodbc_lib_la-database_odbc.lo `test -f 'database_odbc.cpp' || echo '/home/igor/dbhandler/libodbc/'`database_odbc.cpp
libtool: compile:  g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I/home/igor/dbhandler/libodbc -I.. -I../../dbinterface -DUNICODE -DUNIXODBC -I@IODBC_CFLAGS@ -g -O0 -MT libodbc_lib_la-database_odbc.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libodbc_lib_la-database_odbc.Tpo -c /home/igor/dbhandler/libodbc/database_odbc.cpp  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/libodbc_lib_la-database_odbc.o
libtool: compile:  g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I/home/igor/dbhandler/libodbc -I.. -I../../dbinterface -DUNICODE -DUNIXODBC -I@IODBC_CFLAGS@ -g -O0 -MT libodbc_lib_la-database_odbc.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libodbc_lib_la-database_odbc.Tpo -c /home/igor/dbhandler/libodbc/database_odbc.cpp -o libodbc_lib_la-database_odbc.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .deps/libodbc_lib_la-database_odbc.Tpo .deps/libodbc_lib_la-database_odbc.Plo
/bin/sh ../libtool  --tag=CXX   --mode=link g++ -I../../dbinterface -DUNICODE -DUNIXODBC -I@IODBC_CFLAGS@ -g -O0 -L../dbinterface -ldbinterface   -o libodbc_lib.la -rpath /usr/local/lib libodbc_lib_la-database_odbc.lo  
libtool: link: g++  -fPIC -DPIC -shared -nostdlib /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.3.0/../../../../lib64/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.3.0/crtbeginS.o  .libs/libodbc_lib_la-database_odbc.o   -L../dbinterface -ldbinterface -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.3.0 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.3.0/../../../../lib64 -L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.3.0/../../.. -lstdc++ -lm -lc -lgcc_s /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.3.0/crtendS.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.3.0/../../../../lib64/crtn.o  -g -O0   -Wl,-soname -Wl,libodbc_lib.so.0 -o .libs/libodbc_lib.so.0.0.0
libtool: link: (cd ".libs" && rm -f "libodbc_lib.so.0" && ln -s "libodbc_lib.so.0.0.0" "libodbc_lib.so.0")
libtool: link: (cd ".libs" && rm -f "libodbc_lib.so" && ln -s "libodbc_lib.so.0.0.0" "libodbc_lib.so")
libtool: link: ar cru .libs/libodbc_lib.a  libodbc_lib_la-database_odbc.o
libtool: link: ranlib .libs/libodbc_lib.a
libtool: link: ( cd ".libs" && rm -f "libodbc_lib.la" && ln -s "../libodbc_lib.la" "libodbc_lib.la" )
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/igor/dbhandler/Debug/libodbc'
```

I still the variable name there and not their values.

Is it normal?

Comment: Just a few issues with your `odbc_config` based `configure.ac`: Lacks proper m4 quoting. What if `odbc_config` is called something else like `odbc_config.exe`? What if there is no `pkg-config` installed or it is called something else like `mingw64-pkg-config`? There is an extra `odbcinst.pc` file for linking against `odbcinst`. You already know the solution: Use `PKG_CHECK_MODULES` and ignore `odbc_config`. `PKG_CHECK_MODULES` is also easy to replicate in subprojects.

Comment: @ndim, there is no "extension" and especially "exe extension" in *nix-like systems. And Windows is NOT one of them. And they produce different results.

Comment: OSX has a userland based on FreeBSD. It does not get more Unix-like than BSD. They commonly call common GNU/Linux tools by a different name, e.g. `gmake` instead of `make`. Your software should be buildable there, so it should support a different tool name. And at the risk of repeating myself, of course, `PKG_CHECK_MODULES` already supports that and works on all *nix-like systems.

Comment: @ndim, can you look at my latest edit and tell me where I'm wrong? Trying to write this by hand is a complete disaster... ;-) I may check that `PKG_CHECK_MODULE` solution later. Right now I need a `quick and dirty` fix that give me a solution based on where I'm running.

Comment: @ndim, also the complicated part is that configure.ac is in the main project directory and libodbc_lib is a subproject. So I will need to pass that stuff I found from the main project down to subproject.

Comment: See my answer below. Two lines in `configure.ac`, then add the `$(odbc_CFLAGS)` and `$(odbc_LIBS)` to the respective build wars. Duplicate that for any subprojects. Or are you confusing subprojects and recursive make with subdirectories containing another `Makefile.am` file?

Comment: @ndim, so in my code edit2 from the op I just need to drop the `@` symbol in the subproject and it will work?

Comment: Because every subproject is in its own directory with its own Makefile.am. And I don't want to duplicate anything like configure...

Comment: Note the difference between `ODBC_LIB` an `ODBC_LIBS`. Is your project on github or somewhere else public? I could contribute a few patches. Do those "subprojects" have their own `configure.ac` or are they just subdirectories with their own `Makefile.am` all listed in the same top level `configure.ac`'s `AC_CONFIG_FILES`? I guess the "subproject" question should become a separate SO question once you have fixed the `_LIB` vs `_LIBS` typo.

Comment: @ndim, I fixed the typo, but I still see a variable names and not their values. Is it normal? Please see latest edit...

Comment: `-I@ODBC_CFLAGS@` should of course be `@ODBC_CFLAGS@` without a leading `-I`, but for some reason what you are actually using is `-I@IODBC_CFLAGS@` with both `-I` and another capital letter `I` after `@`. In computer languages (unlike in natural languages), single characters matter.

Comment: @ndim, the repo is at github.com/oneeyeman1/dbhandler.git. If you have couple of minutes - could you take a look please? I think I fixed it - it builds fine, but does not link (verified with ldd). Let me know what you think of my latest commit. You will see a subproect in question is inside the libodbc folder. It has its own Makefile.am but no configure scripts.

Comment: And let me know when you done, so I can take a look at your changes.

Comment: @ndim, were you able to clone the repo and look at it?

Answer (score 1):

As UnixODBC upstream does ship and install `*.pc` files, I would expect that file to be both present and correct and therefore I would ignore any `*-config` scripts. The pkg-config system is quite well thought out and works even for quite weird cross compilation environments. The `*.pc` mechanism works well on Linux, on FreeBSD, on OSX, cross-compiling for Windows on Linux, to name a few.

A well-written `_config` program written in portable shell could do the same by basically reproducing much of the `pkg-config` logic in portable shell for each and every `_config` script, hopefully correctly.

However, `odbc_config` is not a portable shell script. It is a binary executable, i.e. it will regularly break for cross-compiling, as the system you **build on** will usually not be able to run programs like `odbc_config` which are built to run on the system you are **building for**.

And even if the flags from the `*.pc` files *were* unsuitable for a very unusual build environment: Using `PKG_CHECK_MODULES` defines appropriate `_CFLAGS` and `_LIBS` variables for the configure script, so even in a very unusual build environments one can always override whatever the `*.pc` file might contain by calling `configure` like

```
../configure ODBC_CFLAGS='-I/weird/stuff -DWEIRD_STRING="moo"' ODBC_LIBS='-L/very/weird/libxyz -lodbc'
```

So... using `odbc_config` has no advantages, upstream already provides a `odbc.pc` file so it is always present, so why not just always use `odbc.pc`?

So, in `configure.ac` (if builds without `odbc.pc` present should fail, otherwise you will have to do some `AC_DEFINE` and/or `AM_CONDITIONAL` to conditionally build with or without ODBC support) do

```
m4_pattern_forbid([PKG_CHECK_MODULES])dnl
PKG_CHECK_MODULES([ODBC], [odbc])
```

and in any subdirectory (what you call "subproject") `Makefile.am` or `Makefile-files` where you need to link somehting against `libodbc`, put, depending on whether you are building an executable

```
bin_PROGRAMS    += foobar
[…]
foobar_CPPFLAGS += $(ODBC_CFLAGS)
foobar_LDADD    += $(ODBC_LIBS)
```

or a (libtool) library

```
lib_LTLIBRARIES    += libfoo.la
[…]
libfoo_la_CPPFLAGS += $(ODBC_CFLAGS)
libfoo_la_LIBADD   += $(ODBC_LIBS)
```

That should work for all native and cross-compile builds in properly set up build environments, and people can still override `odbc_CFLAGS` and `odbc_LIBS` in case of problems.

Of course, you can always `AC_CHECK_PROG` or `AC_PATH_PROG` or `AC_CHECK_TOOL` or `AC_PATH_TOOL` together with an `AC_ARG_VAR` for the `odbc_config` program and then define and `AC_SUBST` an `_CFLAGS` and `_LIBS` variable set to the output of `$ODBC_CONFIG --cflags` and `$ODBC_CONFIG --libs`, respectively, and then then use the `_CFLAGS` and `_LIBS` vars in `Makefile.am`/`Makefile-files` as above.

However, that is a lot of code to write, and with a lot of special cases to consider, and if you have to ask about how to do this you will probably get a lot more wrong than if you just just use `PKG_CHECK_MODULES`.

You can always add something later if the `PKG_CHECK_MODULES` route actually does not work for a use case and which cannot be fixed within the pkg-config framework. Until that time (if it ever happens), I would recommend to just use the simple `PKG_CHECK_MODULES` method and probably be done.

Comment: all this is good and understandable info. However, unixODBC maintainers didn't mention pkg-config, when asked but refer me to odbc_config. Moreover,  when I run both on my Gentoo box, I got different results and I trust odbc_config more as it has everything it needs for the build. So, given that - do you know how to check for this binary in configure.ac?

Comment: In addition I think you contradict yourself- first yousay that PC file is always present,  but then you say `if builds without odbc.pc should fail`.

Comment: @Igor, I think you are reading too much into the unixODBC maintainers' recommendation.  Both tools are maintained by them, and their last updates are both about the same.  From my review of their sources alone, I would be more inclined to trust the `pkg-config` file, but probably they both provide working flags when the appropriate requests are made of them.  But by all means, test!

Comment: @Igor If UnixODBC is not installed on the system, there is no `odbc.pc` on the system, and neither is there an `odbc_config` program. The question now is whether you want your software to fail to build in that case, or do you want to build your software without support for odbc? That decision of yours determines whether `builds without odbc.pc should fail` or not.

Answer (score 0):

> So, I need to add a test in configure.ac to check for odbc_config script presence and pass it along to one of the so files generation

Autoconf has [`AC_PATH_PROG()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.71/html_node/Generic-Programs.html) for checking for a program in the executable search path.  You would of course use [`AC_SUBST()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.71/html_node/Setting-Output-Variables.html) to define one or more output variables by which to convey the results to the generated makefiles.

But no, coming back around to my comment on [the answer to one of your previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73011687/2402272), what you ought to do is not have `configure` forward information about the executable, but rather for it to determine the needed flags itself and forward *them*, via one or more output variables.  If you continue to use `odbc_config`, at least conditionally, then that means having `configure` run it and capture the output.  You should not inject shell command substitutions into your compilation commands.

And if you substitute a different mechanism, whether conditionally or exclusively, then similarly for that.  (That's what your other answer describes with respect to `pkg-config`.)

Comment: yes, I'm trying to determine the flags by using either odbc_config if present and if not - use pjg-config. I don't care about cross-compiling, at least for now - I just need to build it exclusively on Linux. I can manage writing the check for odbc_config and substitute it for pkg-config, but how do I pass it down to my library.

Comment: As this answer already says, @Igor, you use `AC_SUBST` to define an output variable containing the results you want to convey.  I have linked to the docs.  You can then use that as a `make` variable in Automake-generated makefiles.

Comment: please check my OP edit. Thx.

Comment: @Igor, I don't quite get why you are using `AC_DEFUN` instead of just running `AC_CHECK_PROG` directly.  It will probably work, but it's unnecessarily complicated.  Also, you are not consistently quoting (with `[]`) your macro arguments.  That *probably* won't be an issue, but as a matter of safety and style, you should quote.  There are other, less significant style issues that I will not address, as this is not Code Review SE.

Comment: @Igor, the added question about subprojects belongs in its own SO question, and probably needs a lot more information to be provided before it can be answered.

Comment: can you look at my second edit, please?

Comment: @Igor, You will probably find it to be more effective to test for yourself.  Once you have something that works for you, if you want code review then you could consider [Code Review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).